# Changing my blocking play / scala /slick algorithm not to block

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalability, future, slick-3.0

Here is a relatively simple problem, I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

- I'm using Slick to query a DB.
- I know that it gives me back a sequence which is going to have missing values...
- so I want to add them in ... but I don't know the values in advance.
- Then ultimately generate a csv file for someone else to consume...

  ```
  def annualAtomTesting(peril: String , region: String) = Action {

    val theResult: Future[Seq[SingleEventYear]] = db.run(filterAnnualPerilAndRegionFillGaps(peril, region).result)
    val years =  theResult.map { list => list.map(s => s.year).toSet}
    val allYear = (1 to 10000) toSet
    val dbYears = Await.result(  years , Duration.Inf  )
    val theDifference = allYear.diff( dbYears )
    val whatsMissing = theDifference.map(s => new SingleEventYear(region, peril, 0 ,0 , s, 0))
    val intermediate: String = Await.result( theResult.map(result => header + result.mkString("\n") + "\n"
                    + whatsMissing.mkString("\r\n") ), Duration.Inf )

  Ok(intermediate)
  }
  ```

So from a potential series of 1,2,3,4,5 , i might get 2, 4, 5 from the DB query. This code adds in 1 and 3... but my understanding is it will block everything, which is kind of naughty.

For all that I tried, I could not future out how to get the .diff method (which looks like the cleanest strategy) to operate in a 'Future', non-blocking context.

Am I missing something?

Comment: P.s this algorthim is 'correct' i.e produces the correct output, but it itches... I hate that :-)...

Comment: P.P.S I'm relatively new to some of these ideas, so please don't hurt me if the code stinks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have only one Future and you don't need to make several Await.result.
You can get rid of all your Await.result(...) calls by switching to Action.async:

```
Action.async {
  val allYear = (1 to 10000).toSet
  val intermediate:Future[String] = for (
    res <- db.run(filterAnnualPerilAndRegionFillGaps(peril, region).result)
  ) yield (
    header + res.mkString("\n") + "\n" + 
    allYear.diff(res.map (s => s.year).toSet).map(s => new SingleEventYear(region, peril, 0 ,0 , s, 0)).mkString("\r\n")
  )
  intermediate.map(item => Ok(item))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of how to do this:

```
def annualAtomTesting(peril: String, region: String) = Action.async {
  for {
    results <- db.run(filterAnnualPerilAndRegionFillGaps(peril, region).result)
    years = results.map(_.year).toSet
    allYears = (1 to 10000).toSet
    differences = allYears diff years
    missing = differences.map(new SingleEventYear(region, peril, 0, 0, _, 0))
    intermediate = header + results.mkString("\n") + "\n" + missing.mkString("\r\n")
  } yield Ok(intermediate)
}
```

You should not use `Await` in production code. Play allows you to use async actions that require you to return `Future[Result]` instead of `Result`.

If you really want to think about your code with `await` you can use scala async like this:

```
import scala.async.Async._
def annualAtomTesting(peril: String, region: String) = Action.async {
  async {
    val results: Seq[SingleEventYear] = await(db.run(filterAnnualPerilAndRegionFillGaps(peril, region).result))
    val years = results.map(_.year).toSet
    val allYears = (1 to 10000).toSet
    val differences = allYears diff years
    val missing = differences.map(new SingleEventYear(region, peril, 0, 0, _, 0))
    val intermediate = header + results.mkString("\n") + "\n" + missing.mkString("\r\n")
    Ok(intermediate)
  }
}
```

You can call `await` on any `Future` in `async` block and it will return the result, maybe that approach might seem easier, but it has limitations. It will be changed using macros to flatMaps. The `async { Ok("res") }` is an expression of type `Future[Result]`. This allows you to put it inside `Action.async {}` and keep your code asynchronous.